# jQuery timers not starting on document-ready

Tags: jquery

This works fine:

```
$('.mainRotatorPaginator a').click(function() {
    $(this).everyTime(1000, 'rotation', function(i) {
        $('.mainRotatorPaginator').css('outline', '1px solid green'); //test

    });
});
```

But I want a timer to start as soon as the page loads, not to wait for a user event.

I'm following the examples at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers, but this just isn't doing anything:

```
$(document).everyTime(1000, function (i) {
    $('.mainRotatorPaginator').css('outline', '1px solid green'); //test
}, 10);
```

Any help?

**SOLUTION**

OK, turns out the solution is related to Samich's (and Joe's) answer: even though all my jQuery calls were already nested inside $(document).ready in a file containing all my custom jQuery code, I tried pasting the suggestion anyway, just for giggles. To my surprise, this worked, and it turns out it's because I'd pasted the plugin inside the outer $(document).ready, but at the bottom, after the $(document).everyTime() call, so the file's code reached my call first, and the plugin's functions weren't yet defined.

So the best thing is to stick the plugin in it's own $(document).ready(function());, and place above the block where all my custom jQuery resides. (and I'll minify it first -- wondering why they don't  offer a minified version?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).everyTime(1000, function (i) {
        $('.mainRotatorPaginator').css('outline', '1px solid green'); //test
    }, 10);
});
```

According to this post [jquery "everyTime" function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860349/jquery-everytime-function) you can specify interval as string value

```
$(document).everyTime('1s', function (i) { })
```

Comment: The code samples are already nested within $(document).ready(function(){   });  My apologies -- I thought that would be apparent given that I stated the first sample was working.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).everyTime(1000, function (i) {
        $('.mainRotatorPaginator').css('outline', '1px solid green'); //test
    }, 10);
});
```

Comment: The code samples are already nested within $(document).ready(function(){   });  My apologies -- I thought that would be apparent given that I stated the first sample was working.