# Automatic save when changing an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement an automatic save using javascript/jQuery.

I have several (hundreds) of `overlay-rotation-bounding-box`-id elements. For example, `overlay-rotation-bounding-box-968` would be the 968th element on my list. I want to auto save every time I change one of these elements. I'm kinda new to this so I tried to make it really simple and I used this snippet:

```
var autosaveOn = false;
        console.log(autosaveOn)
        function myAutosavedTextbox_onTextChanged() {
            console.log(autosaveOn);
            if (!autosaveOn) {
                autosaveOn = true;

                $('#overlay-rotation-bounding-box').everyTime("30", function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "autosavecallbackurl",
                        data: "id=1",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
                        }
                    });
                }); //closing tag
            }
        }
```

However, it does nothing. I guess I'm selecting the element in the wrong way. What is the correct way to develop a auto save function for an element that appears more than once and the id is based on its index?

Kind regards

Comment: Give them all the same class and use `this` inside the event handler.  `$(".list-input").on("change", function() { autoSave(this); });`

Comment: I can't give the same class to all of the elements since I need to select them individually. That's the tough part, I guess

Comment: It comes from the selector you're using. You don't have a selector called: overlay-rotation-bounding-box

Comment: Why do you need to "select them individually" - there's no evidence of that in your question.  Adding a class doesn't equate to removing the id.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change selector like this:

```
$('[id^=overlay-rotation-bounding-box]').everyTime.......
```

Comment: It's not triggering anything

Comment: This should select all the `IDs` starting with `overlay-rotation-bounding-box` no matter what number is in the end of the ID attribute.

Comment: When/Where this `myAutosavedTextbox_onTextChanged()` is called?

Comment: That is not shown in the code but OP has problem inside the function so we can consider that it would be called.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion where it should be added, regarding this problem? This could be the problem, indeed.

Comment: `myAutosavedTextbox_onTextChanged()` this function should be called after it had been defined. please add a called at the end of your script

Comment: Yes, I did it and I'm getting `$(...).everyTime is not a function`

Comment: That's good, go ahead and see how to use everyTime here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860349/jquery-everytime-function)

Comment: "*it does nothing*" could also imply that OP is not calling the function (now there's an error within, safe to assume it's being called)